# Adding Comment to a folder in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

In mac we can arrange folder according to name, type, size and comments.
My question is how do we add comments to a folder?

Comment: It's a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 4):

In Finder select the directory. Choose Get Info and choose Get Info and add to Spotlight comments